# How to convert all files in a directory to files of the same name but of a different format in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory full of JPEGs. I want to convert every one of them to PNGs of the same name. I tried `convert *.jpg *.png` but I just ended up with a bunch of PNGs with names "*-0.png", "*-1.png", etc.

Is there a way to preserve the name of the files when iterating through the entire directory?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150) should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the mogrify command rather than the convert command.

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

From the `mogrify` man page

> Mogrify overwrites the original image file, whereas, convert(1) writes
>   to a different image file.